# GLobiflow Json decoding

Tags: podio

just need some real help here
ive been stuck on this for quite a long time
how do i get the "description" value from this json
ive tried json decode also base64encode then decode
but i cant get values when json responses are like this
its from this endpoint
https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A2xF.png)

Answer (score 0):

In a variable action, I'd try:

json_decode(`(Variable) test2`, true)["itemListElement"][0]["result"]["description"]

Comment: GlobiFlow is probably dying on the slashes in the json. It's a know issue. You could use ProcFu to saften your payload. Then the json decide will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `htmlspecialchars_decode` to have it as a simple string, then `current ( array_slice ( explode ( '"', [variable] ) , 2 ) )` replace `2` with the number of `"` before description, it will give you what you want.